# How do I check if the attachment variable is empty before adding it to mail message?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have managed to send email from my SSIS package using the script task with VB.NET code. I am not good at scripting, I basically looked at various scripts online to get me to where I am. The problem I have is that I have set up all my variables in my SSIS package in BIDS and I have set them to *ReadOnly* in my package.

Everything works fine if I specify a value for my *Attachment* package variable but if I don't, then my script fails. I don't always want to send an attached file when I send an email with my script. I would like the code to be modified so that if there is no value specified for my *Attachement* variable in my SSIS package in BIDS then my script task will only send the message in the body and not fail.

Also if possible when, attachments are sent would like to be able to send multiple attachments. I have also realised that now that I have set up my script as it seems that I no longer need the the *`SendMail Task`* in SSIS everything works just from the script and my variables set in SSIS.

Shouldn't I be able to connect the *`Script Task`* to the *`Send Mail Task`* to make them work together?

Here is my Script Task code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net

<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum

Public Sub Main()

    MsgBox(Dts.Variables("Username").Value.ToString)

    Dim myHtmlMessage As MailMessage
    Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient

    Dim mailAuthentication As System.Net.NetworkCredential
    mailAuthentication = New System.Net.NetworkCredential( _
        Dts.Variables("Username").Value.ToString(), _
        Dts.Variables("Password").Value.ToString())

    myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage( _
         Dts.Variables("From").Value.ToString(), _
         Dts.Variables("To").Value.ToString(), _
         Dts.Variables("Subject").Value.ToString(), _
         Dts.Variables("Body").Value.ToString())

    myHtmlMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Dts.Variables("Attachments").Value.ToString))
    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient(Dts.Variables("SMTPServer").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("Port").Value.ToString())
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False

    mySmtpClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = True
    mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlMessage)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic to check the variable before adding the value to mail attachment

- Change the following line in your script to check if the value in variable *`Attachments`* is not empty using the function *`String.IsNullOrEmpty`*.
- It is always a good practice to prefix the scope of the variable like **`User::`** or **`System::`** when using package variables inside the `Script Task`.
- To add one more condition, you can check if the file actually exists in the specified path using function *`System.IO.File.Exists`* before adding it to the mail attachment.

#### From:

```
myHtmlMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Dts.Variables("Attachments").Value.ToString))
```

#### To:

```
Dim attachment As String = Dts.Variables("User::Attachments").Value.ToString()

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment) Then
    If System.IO.File.Exists(attachment) Then
        myHtmlMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(attachment))
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

"Shouldn't I be able to connect the Script Task to the Send Mail Task to make them work together?"

You can make the `Send Email Task` dynamic by using the [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137547.aspx) (third tab). Expression allow you to make anything in an SSIS package behave differently based on values. As you can see, most any property you'd need to modify is exposed in the drop down list.

[image]